# preg_replace to replace string that contains "[" and "]"

Tags: php, preg-replace

How do I write a preg_replace string that convert:

```
"[[ STRING1 | STRING 2 ]]"
```

to

```
<a href='STRING 2'>STRING1</a>
```

in PHP? I having trouble matching the characters "[","]" and "|" as they are reserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace('~\[\[(.+)\|(.+)\]\]~iUs','<a href="$2">$1</a>',$string);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a  `\` before the symbol to escape them: `\[`, `\]` and `\|`.

Answer (score 1):

Just escape them in your regexp : `"["` => `"\["`

Comment: arg too late, quick! to the time machine!

Answer (score 0):

As other already said, you have to escape any special characters, using `\`. You can also use [preg_quote](http://php.net/preg_quote) to escape the text passed to regular expressions (extremly usefull if you are building dinamic regexps)